# Remove IPSEC policy from W2k3 DC

Tags: windows-server-2003, ipsec

I just can't for the life of me remember. We were setting up IPSEC for a VPN along time ago and added IPSEC that has always caused 1091 1085 errors. We are not using it so I would like to remove it but cant find where.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a DC, it doesn't have local policies, so this has to be managed by a domain GPO.

You should find the GPO which is setting this and edit/disable/delete it.

Inside the GPO editor, you can find IPSec settings in Computer Settings -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> IP Security Policies.

Comment: just dont remove any other possible IPSec policy you use internally^^

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But nothing is enabled there. Any other ideas?